# conda command line for pip install -r requirements.txt

Tags: python, anaconda

In Anaconda environment, what is the corresponding conda command line for

```
pip install -r requirements.txt
```

Comment: The equivalent is `conda create`, but they're not identical. The linked duplicate may not look like the same question at first glance—but it should not only answer your question, but also show you how to do almost anything you're likely to want. If it doesn't, explain what's missing and we can reopen your question to answer that (or edit the answer, or add another one, to the dup, depending).

Comment: (Also, if your questions are answered by the external links in Shan Dou's answer, but not by the answer itself, please explain that as well, so we can make sure SO stands on its own even if those links go down.)